# How to display "no matches found" in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using this search form on my website and it's working fine
and here is the *JavaScript* code

```
function search() {
  input = document.getElementById('searchInput');
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();

  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('#element');

  for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    title = elements[i].querySelector('#title').querySelector('p');
    if (title.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      elements[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      elements[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

I want to display "no matches found" if a user enters a word that doesn't exist on my website.

Comment: You would just output it in your `else` condition. Also, your `elements` variable is querying **multiple** `#element` tags, which would be invalid markup -- IDs must be unique throughout the document.

Comment: yes, `querySelectorAll('#element')` should, in valid HTML only ever return a single element, as ID's are unique in *valid* HTML

Comment: @JaromandaX you can always suggest/make one yourself too

Comment: Which part do you have a problem with, @Stephen? The part where you display "no matches found" or the part where you determine that you need to display "no matches found"?

Comment: note, `title = elements[i].querySelector('#title').querySelector('p');` is just `title = elements[i].querySelector('#title p');` - but still, there *should* only be one element in the whole document with `id="title"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the floowing condition to your loop

```
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    title = elements[i].querySelector('#title').querySelector('p');
    if (title.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      elements[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      elements[i].style.display = "none";
    }


    if(i===elements.length){
       alert("no matches found")
    }    


  }
```

Comment: Ok, then pls accept and upvote the answer for stack overflow community